# How to change a webpage client-side?

Tags: css, web

There are a lot of webpages that I actually hate because of their design/lack of info.

Every time I open one of that page I would like to have an script that automatically changes from the original webpage to my already "hacked" webpage.

For example, changing the css completely, or adding some custom links somewhere in the page.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? can you give an example of a page you _hate_ and how it will be displayed after your _hacking_?

Comment: Changing the look of every webpage according to your requirement is like changing the behavior of every individual you talk to.. :) You can try the below mentioned option but every website uses own structure so i am kinda sure it will not be as fruitful as you are think ... :)

Comment: @Joum I don't know, it could be something as simple as changing the google.com background-color to black just client-side.

Comment: @AtulPundhir I'm not talking about changing every page I don't like to  it's better, I'm talking about one at a time.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'll have to second @akostadinov 's answer. Keep in mind that it will only work in the browser you are using. Basically you would have to do some sort of _extension_ for your browser. But of course, this can be done in Firefox (like akostadinov said), in Chrome... Probably others too, but I can't vouch for it...

Comment: I understand that .. you can only change the page which you are viewing not all.. But they all are not same.. correct . Lets say you create custom extension or you use ready made and you change the css for h1 p ul and li elements.. but if DOM structure is not proper of the webpage and you change the position using your extension if may break the look and feel completely..

Comment: @AtulPundhir And if I have the resources, I would be able to make an extension just to change one page, right?

Comment: You can only change the look and feel of the webpage which is loaded in your browser ..

Comment: @Atul That's what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Greasemonkey` or `Scriptish` firefox extensions for the purpose. I guess similar addons exist for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Fiddler for this task by a [Fiddler script](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse).
Fiddler would act as proxy which would apply then the hacks.
This is a client side proxy and would support multiple browsers.

Comment: This sounds really interesting and powerful, but don't you think it might be a bit _overkill_ if the idea is just to play around with the design of the page?